# Running a go container in Codenvy (Next-Generation Beta)

Tags: codenvy

Do you know of any descriptions on how to run a Dockerfile in Codenvy (Next-Generation Beta). I have tried to look for how you reference a Dockerfile as there is no template for docker?

I can install go from the console alright, but it would be nice just to reference docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference or author a custom dockerfile in the dashboard. These docs explain more: https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/recipes

In order to get the built-in terminal its simplest to inherit from a Codenvy base image, but you can also tweak any dockerfile to work with Codenvy as well. It's all covered in the same page.

As a note we'll be redoing this section of our docs to make it more clear.